# C# Add Field aliases with repository

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have the following controller method:

```
public IActionResult Get()
{
    IEnumerable<Hour> _hours = _hourRepository
        .AllIncluding(h => h.Customer.name, h => h.Payer.name)
        .OrderByDescending(h => h.hourdate)
        .ToList();

    return Ok(_hours);
}
```

I want to change the method to use aliases because both `Customer` and `Payer` return the same name field.

```
public IActionResult Get()
{
    IEnumerable<Hour> _hours = _hourRepository
        .AllIncluding(
                 h => new { customer_name = h.Customer.name }, 
                 h => new { payer_name = h.Payer.name })
        .OrderByDescending(h => h.hourdate)
        .ToList();

     return Ok(_hours);
}
```

This however results in an error as I use a repository which does not support this ... I think.

> The property expression 'h => new <>f__AnonymousType1`1(customer_name
>   = h.Customer.name)' is not valid. The expression should represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'

Below my repository:

```
public virtual IEnumerable<T> AllIncluding(params Expression<Func<T, 
                                       object>>[] includeProperties)
{
    IQueryable<T> query = _context.Set<T>();
    foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties)
    {
        query = query.Include(includeProperty);
    }
    return query.AsEnumerable();
}
```

How would I change the repository method `AllIncluding` to accept both options as described above?

Comment: From what I see, even the first method can't work. You can't include an expression like `h => h.Customer.name`, only `h => h.Customer`. Next, you get an object graph in which each object has its own unique property names, there can't be any conflicts.

Comment: ah, that explains. I only want to return the names though, any ideas?

Comment: Then you should return a *projection*: `Select(h => new SomeDto  { CustomerName = h.Customer.Name, PayerName = h.Payer.Name }`.

Comment: ty - will look into projections